# How to access NativeWindow in pure AS3 AIR project

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, mxml

I'm getting crazy because I can't access object NativeWindow in a "ActionScript Mobile Project", no matter what I do stage.nativeWindow is always null when I test on desktop. If I create a new NativeWindow then it's the stage property that is null. Oddly enough accessing stage.NativeWindow works when deploying on blackberry playbook but not when debugging configuration Launch Method on desktop.

Can't answer my own question but it seems the feature is just unsupported on the desktop I guess the workaround is use Stage.Resize when debugging desktop.

reference:
The window represents the native operating system window; the Stage represents the content contained by the window. This property is only valid for content running in AIR on platforms that support the NativeWindow class. On other platforms, this property will be null. In Flash Player (content running in a browser), this property will also be null.

Comment: If you create a sample app http://pastebin.com/bEkUsPST you'll be able to get native window even in constructor. Please try to reproduce your problem on an empty project.

Comment: @Maxim Kachurovskiy It does reproduce the problem, I create new ActionScript Mobile project and run Debug Configuration Desktop Emulation of Android/IOS/PLaybook, always null :( it still doesn't work. Output from the console is : null
[SWF] SampleAS3AIR.swf
[Unload SWF] SampleAS3AIR .swf

Comment: You're right. `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activeWindow` and `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows` are also empty. Well it's just a bug, you can file it to bugs.adobe.com, they usually get fixed. Try to create your app without debugging on desktop or write if-else for all `nativeWindow` usages for now.

Comment: Also when you try to write `var w:* = new NativeWindow(...)` and then see `w` properties in debugger the `adl.exe` fails :)

Comment: @Maxim Thanks a lot for reproducing it Maxim ! very helpful. I'm not sure if it's a bug though, maybe there's just no support of NativeWindow in the Desktop Simulator by design or something... who knows. I'll wait a bit and mark your answer if I don't find anything. spasiba

Comment: It's really a deal braker for me though as I can't see how the IPhone / IPad application will look like. I will be forced to fork the 100$ iDevelopperFee only to know if it shows correctly or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access nativeWindow in mobile devices it's not supported. Check this page it's - unsupported apis on mobile devices
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS789ea67d3e73a8b24b55b57a124b32b5b57-7fff.html

Comment: +1. And a little more information on [AIR device profiles](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS144092a96ffef7cc16ddeea2126bb46b82f-8000.html)